# Missing vendor files on a fresh installation

Tags: magento2

i have a fresh magento 2 install, and i'm missing files and components, any ideia of what should i be missing?

I miss the file JsonFactory for example, and i don't have any modal component available..

a bit of my ui_configuration.xsd

```
<!-- Components list -->
<xs:element type="formConfiguration" name="form"/>
<xs:element type="containerConfiguration" name="container"/>
<xs:element type="listingConfiguration" name="listing"/>
```

and the one from the magento repo

```
 <!-- Components list -->
<xs:element type="formConfiguration" name="form"/>
<xs:element type="modalConfiguration" name="modal"/>
<xs:element type="dynamicRowsConfiguration" name="dynamicRows"/>
<xs:element type="containerConfiguration" name="container"/>
<xs:element type="listingConfiguration" name="listing"/>
```

anyone knows why i'm missing things?

Answer (score 1):

OK i got an answer for this.. --' the code i was seeing its from the branch "develop".. so its not on the release version, well this is stupid because on magento site they have already documentation for things they don't have on release version.

like this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-modal.html